# Odds convergence in binomial probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, binomial-distribution

In a Bernoulli process with a random variable that is 1 with a probability $p$ and 0 with probability $q = 1 - p$, after $N$ repetitions one uses $\hat{p} = \frac{N_1}{N}$ as estimator of $p$, and then $\langle\hat{p}\rangle = p$ and $\langle\hat{p}^2\rangle = \frac{p(1-p)}{N}$ as $P(N_1)$ is a binomial distribution.

How does the estimator $\hat{z}$ of $z = \frac{p}{q}$ converge as a function of p and N? In other words, what is $\langle\hat{z}^2\rangle(N,p)$?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Are you saying you use $\hat{z} = {N_1 \over N - N_1}$ as an estimator for $z = {p \over q}$?  Since $Prob(N_1 = N) = Prob(\hat{z} = \infty) > 0$, wouldn't this mean $\langle \hat{z} \rangle = \infty$?

Comment: I guess you are right, but then my question is: how would you give an estimate and a confidence interval for $z$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_estimator has some ideas on how to estimate a ratio without bias, but honestly I am not an expert and have not read through that article.  Hope you find it somewhat helpful...

Comment: Confidence interval might be a different matter though, as you can find the smallest $p_s$ and the largest $p_l$ for which the observed $N_1=n$ still happens with some probability bound $\alpha$ (e.g. one-sided).  This gives you a range $[p_s, p_l]$ which then maps to $[z_s, z_l]$.  The mapping is highly non-linear but it is still a confidence interval as in: any $z$ in the interval meets the probability bound and any $z$ outside doesn't.